# Conjunction (AND operator) of IN operator in Python

Tags: python, in-operator, and-operator

I'd like to understand why the conjunction of results of IN operator in Python it not working as regular conjunction.

Example:

1. `False and False and True = False` *(obvious)*
2. `'a' in 'ccc' and 'b' in 'ccc' and 'c' in 'ccc' = False` *(ok)*
3. `'a' and 'b' and 'c' in 'ccc' = True` *(blows my mind)*

I'd expect that the third line would return the same values as the first and second ones, but it's not.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Operation results in true as:

```
result = 'a' and 'b' and 'c' in 'ccc'
#is the same as
result = bool('a') and bool('b') and bool('c' in 'ccc')
#i.e
result = True and True and True #which is true
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```py
'a' and 'b' and 'c' in 'ccc' = True
```

considers 3 conditions:

```py
'a'
```

```py
'b'
```

```py
'c' in 'ccc'
```

Empty strings are seen as `False`, while non-empty strings (of any length) yield `True`. So, `a` yields `True` and `b` yields `True`. For `'c' in 'ccc'`, you already mentioned in your OP you understand that.
Lastly, to sum up

```py
True and True and True == True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are strict rules on [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), which is how expression is implicitly "parenthesized".  `in` has higher precedence, so it is evaluated first, before any of conjunctions.